# Why does this request have such a high latency?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to make a discord bot that gets some information about a cryptocurrency, but for some reason it takes 45+ seconds for the request to complete.

Code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def rate(ctx, *args):
    t1 = perf_counter()
    if len(args) == 1:
        async with ctx.typing():
            coin = args[0]
            t2 = perf_counter()
            print(t2 - t1)
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                #try:
                if True:
                    async with session.get(f'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids={coin}&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=false&include_24hr_vol=false&include_24hr_change=true&include_last_updated_at=false', ssl=True) as r:
                        t2 = perf_counter()
                        print(t2 - t1)
                        r = await r.json()
                        #try:
                        if True:
                            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{coin.capitalize()} rate", color=await color())
                            embed.add_field(name="Current price", value=f'${r[f"{coin}"]["usd"]}')
                            embed.add_field(name="24 Hour Change", value=f'{r[f"{coin}"]["usd_24h_change"]}%')
                            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                        #except:
                            #embed = discord.Embed(title='Something went wrong...', description="The coin you provided was invalid. Make sure you don't enter the abbreviation, but the whole name. Example: `$rate bitcoin`", color=await color())
                            #await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                #except:
                    #embed = discord.Embed(title='Something went wrong...', description="Something went wrong on our side. It looks like we couldn't connect to a required API. Try again later.", color=await color())
                    #await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="An error occured", description="Make sure to specify one coin.", color=await color())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I have included a counter to check elapsed time and have commented out except functions so errors display in the console.
This is what I see in the console;

```
0.17547020000000657
58.81905819999997
```

Is there any fix for this? Do I need to use another requests library?

Edit 1: making the request through my browser or reqbin takes less than a second

Comment: If there are many other items executing in the event loop or if you have some heavily CPU-bound task that executes, it could take a very long time for the async `session.get` to be executed, and thus a long time to return a value.

Comment: @Stephen that isn't it, because when I use `requests.get` with the `requests` module through the command line it still takes 50 seconds. I've tried to host the bot through repl.it and I don't get delays now, so I guess it's something on my end.